# Adding rewrite code to prevent hotlinking in a htaccess file in wordpress

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking

I wish to alter the standard .htaccess file in wordpress to prevent hotlinking to our files in the uploads folder. I have put together the code below but sadly the files still are accesible directly, something we would like to prevent.

Anybody here that can tell me where I went wrong ?

thanks

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)mysite.be/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|zip|rar|mp3|flv|swf|xml|png|css|pdf)$ - [F]


# END WordPress
```

Comment: An empty HTTP_REFERER fails the second RewriteCond, so the RewriteRule isn't enforced.  Perhaps you're missing an [OR] ?

Comment: "the files still are accesible directly" - Although a direct request isn't strictly "hotlinking"? You generally need to allow "direct" requests (ie. an empty `Referer` header) due to some user-agents legitimately suppressing the `Referer` header.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille An _empty_ HTTP_REFERER fails the **first** RewriteCond (the second would otherwise be _successful_ since it does _not_ match the regex).

Comment: ...and you should avoid manually editing between the `BEGIN WordPress` / `END WordPress` comment markers since WP itself maintains this code block and might overwrite your manual edits in a future update.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)mysite.be/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|zip|rar|mp3|flv|swf|xml|png|css|pdf)$ - [F]
```

Comment: If you are going to add the `OR` flag to the first (negated) condition then you might as well remove the first condition altogether.

Comment: You could have a point there.